# Using watir-webdriver on windows

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, watir

I have been using watir for a long time with Internet Explorer. I am just now trying to get watir-webdriver to work. I have installed `IEDriverServer.exe` in my path.

I have a website running on my local machine that is listening on port 80 and I am attempting to hit that site with my watir tests. Normally under watir (without webdriver) IE will simply launch and hit whatever URL I specify, such as `http://MY-MACHINE-NAME/default.aspx`. However, when IEDriverServer launches it appears to be listening on some random port such as 5555. So, IE will launch and show something like `http://localhost:5555/` in the address bar. After that, I get an error with the stack trace below.

I think I have a basic misunderstanding with regards to how to get watir to hit my website on port 80 using webdriver, just as it did without it. Any hints would be most appreciated.

Thanks

```
C:\Home\Server\Test\Watir\web>ruby ViewOrgBillingProfiles_test.rb --name test_04_filtering
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.31.0.0
Listening on port 5555
C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connec
t(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `open'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `block in connect'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1284:in `request'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `response_for'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:38:in `request'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:598:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:576:in `execute'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:189:in `quit'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:59:in `quit'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.25.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:166:in `quit'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:87:in `close'
    from C:/Home/Server/Test/Watir/shared/setup.rb:1:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Home/Server/Test/Watir/shared/setup.rb:45:in `start_ie': undefined method `speed=' for #<Watir::Browser:0x..fdf634488 closed=false> (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Home/Server/Test/Watir/shared/setup.rb:106:in `<top (required)>'
    from         C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/DevInstallations/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from ViewOrgBillingProfiles_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: please share relevant ruby code

Comment: I managed to get past this problem. Thanks. My problem now is 1) trying to get chromedriver.exe logging to stop dumping out into the test results output, and 2) trying to get stackoverflow to notify me of responses to my questions!

Comment: If you have fixed the problem, let us know what the solution was.

Comment: If you have another problem, create a new question.

Comment: I get e-mail notification from stack overflow when new answers are posted to my questions. I have checked the preferences, but I did not find a setting for that.

Answer (score 0):

Way late on this, but if you look at selenium webdriver in `C:\Systemtest\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\selenium-webdriver-2.47.1\lib\selenium\webdriver\ie\bridge.rb` you'll see that the default port is set to 5555:

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module IE

      #
      # @api private
      #

      class Bridge < Remote::Bridge

        HOST            = Platform.localhost
        DEFAULT_PORT    = 5555
        DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 30
```